# Images not properly uploading

Tags: php

I tried to create a gallery using php admins can upload multiple images all the images are uploading correctly like the image is saving in the database as much as I can but the problem is that the image is saving once in the folder

Like loop runs images name saves in the database twice

Forexampl
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg

this is what comes in database but when i open the the folder i see
img1.jpg the rest are not coming

here is my code

```
        $imggall = $_FILES["gallery_img"]["name"];
        $imgtype = $_FILES["gallery_img"]["type"];
        $imgtemp = $_FILES["gallery_img"]["tmp_name"];
        foreach($imggall as $key => $imgname) {
            $path = "./img/gallery/".$imgname;
            foreach($imgtemp as $key1 => $imgtemp1) {
                move_uploaded_file($imgtemp1, $path);
            }
            $confirm = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO gallery (image) VALUES ('$imgname')");
        }
```

Here is the HTML form for the page post.php

```
<p>
            <form method="POST" action="post.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="title">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Category</label>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM category");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                            if(!empty($row["cat_name"])) {
                    ?>

                    <label><input type="checkbox" name='catname' value="<?php echo $row["cat_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["cat_name"]; ?></label>

                    <?php } } ?>

                    <?php
                        $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM category");
                        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
                            if($row1["parent"] !== "None") {
                    ?>

                    <label><input type="checkbox" name='catname' value="<?php echo $row1["parent"]; ?>"><?php echo $row1["parent"]; ?></label>

                    <?php } } ?>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Featured Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="ft_img">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="descrip" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Featured</label>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name='fetch' value="Featured">Featured</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Android Button</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="android">
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Iphone Button</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="iphone">
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Custom Button Text</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="cbtn_text">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Custom Button Link</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="cbtn_url">
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
                var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
                var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

                var x = 1; //initlal text box count
                $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                        x++; //text box increment
                        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group"><input type="file" name="gallery_img[]" style="float:left;" /><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a><div class="clear"></div></div>'); //add input box
                    }
                });

                $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
                })
            });

            </script>

            <div class="input_fields_wrap form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                <button class="add_field_button btn btn-default">Add More Fields</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gallery Images</label>
                <input type="file" name="gallery_img[]">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default purple-btn" value="Submit" name="posts" />
                <input type="Reset" class="btn btn-default purple-btn" value="Reset Value" />
                <a href="cat.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
            </div>

            </form>
            </p>
```

Comment: Added HTML please review

Comment: please do a `var_dump($_FILES)` and see how images are coming to your server, and then just loop over FILES array

Answer (score 1):

looping twice may effect performance, this code works for me in my gallery

```
<?php 
    $files = $_FILES['gallery_img']['name'];
    $fileCount = count($files);
    for($i=0; $i<$fileCount; $i++) {
       $tmpFilePath = $files[$i];
       if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
           $newFilePath = "./img/gallery/" . $files[$i];
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            // if files are uploaded then only insert into database
             $confirm = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO gallery (image) VALUES ('$files[$i]')");
          }
      }
    }
   ?>
```

Hope this may work

Comment: Any one to help e out